# Why can't I see a custom controller Index view on my hosted site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have deployed an ASP.NET MVC3 site to heathermcinerney.com.  The basic links are accessible through the default home controller.  I created a ClientsController with an Index and a Create view.  The Index will not display even though I added routing.MapRoutes in my global.asax.cs file (see below).  I can add '/Create' after 'Clients' in the url (which didn't display my Index) and see my form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace HeatherPAX
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Clients", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Clients", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have Index action in your Clients controller? What is its content? Side note: your Clients route hides default one.

Comment: Yes, I have Index, Listings, About, Contacts, and Clients as Actions.

Comment: Their views are beneath home in the corresponding .cshtml files.  I have a Clients folder beneath view with Index and Create.  I figured that I just needed to add routes.MapRoute to clients in order to view this.

Comment: Actually you don't need to create that maproute. You're using the "normal" urls and the framework by convention takes index as the default action

Comment: @Andrei - The Index action on the clients controller just returns a view, which is an HTML action link to ("Create new client", "Create").  This is accessible when running in VS2010.  On the host, I don't reach this Index, but I can explicitly type http://www.heathermcinerney.com/Clients/Create and see the form which is under the view associated with the Clients controller.  I feel like the Index is being misinterpreted, but I explicitly define two different routes above.